# Web2py - mysql - how to DAL?

Tags: mysql, web2py

I would like to drop to command prompt with models imported to run some queries.

I have mysql database, I am running the following command to achieve the above task

```
$ python web2py.py -S appname -M
.....
>>> db = DAL('mysql://user:password@localhost/db_name')
```

The above command doesn't throw any error. The user/pass and db name are correct as I am able to query the data in mysql prompt successfully.

But now after consulting the docs http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#select, I try to do a select on a table, which gives me below error

```
 $ db(db.category).select()
 AttributeError: 'DAL' object has no attribute 'category'
```

Can you please help me out here? How can I access the data. I am looking to do it DAL way as I need to further embed it into controllers.

FYI.. I am able to use the executesql correctly, without error

```
$ db.executesql('select * from category;')
((1L,
  u'tmp',
  u'T',
  datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 27, 16, 14, 59),
  None,
  datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 27, 16, 14, 59),
  None))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db` is already defined in your models, which are executed since you passed the `-M` option. There's no need to define it again!

Comment: What do you mean "There's no need to define it again!" - what does he need to do to get the code to work?

Comment: By making `db = DAL('mysql://user:password@localhost/db_name')` he's replacing the previous `db` object defined in their models. So he just need to remove that line.